# Certain websites fail to load in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet, javascript

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not able to post questions on Ask Ubuntu in Chrome, apparently because of a dependency on JavaScript from another domain.

I know this isn't an issue with the website. It might be an issue with Chrome, which I recently installed. In Chrome alone I have this issue... it doesn't allow external JavaScript to load. Google is also not opening in Chrome.

See this red banner displayed at the top of all pages on Ask Ubuntu:

[image: Ask Ubuntu displays banner]

> Ask Ubuntu requires external Javascript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

Comment: i said newly installed chrome. nothing in it. fresh os with fresh browser. thats why confused. if there anyextension means will remove but nothing in it. its like empty box not even a history in it

Comment: It's still showing *connection is not private* error after resetting Chrome settings to default.

Comment: Try using Firefox as Browser, because the problem can be Google Chrome.

Comment: You're right, it works in Firefox, but this does not answer the question which says *In Chrome alone it's not working fine; it doesn't allow JavaScript to load.*

Comment: Could you please try to load the URLs https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js and https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js in Chrome? What happens when you do?

Answer (score 1):

> If you receive this message:
>
> > Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain which is blocked or
> >     failed to load.
>
> The Stack Exchange sites fetch jQuery JavaScript libraries from a
>   Google domain. When these fail to load, the "external JavaScript"
>   warning is shown (but only when the SE JavaScript from another domain,
>   `sstatic.net` does load successfully).
>
> So: be sure that `ajax.googleapis.com` is not blocked by, for example:
>
> - a firewall
> - add-ons such as Privoxy or SafeScript
> - a malicious virus with a DNS-changer

<sub>**Source:** ["Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message/89460#89460)</sub>

Comment: still it showing connection is not private error

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js to one that you can visit normally. Install the *Redirector* addon for Firefox, chrome or opera. Then edit the redirecting URL pattern in its options as in the attached screenshot.[image: Redirector Option]